# Random codes writer

Tags: random

some years ago i found a site who writes radnom codes alone... so when you press on a key he displays random codes. the  background was black and the codes green, pls help me, i really want to find it :(

i tried to search on google things like:

- random code writer
- code generator

and a lot of this examples

it looks like:

```
   static string FromBase64(string str)
{
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
using (var msIn = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
using (var msOut = new MemoryStream()) {
using (var ds = new DeflateStream(msIn, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
        ds.CopyTo(msOut);
}
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msOut.ToArray());
}
 <?php
$selfClosing = explode
$html = '
<p><a href="#">foo</a></p>
<hr/>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure are you trying to find a code to make such a thing or you're just searching for something already created?
If you're looking for something already created you can take a look [HERE](http://hackertyper.net/)